# How can I wait for a response before moving on in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently working on a Chrome Extension.

content_script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var IPToken;
    function doSomething() {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method: "getToken"}, function(response) {               
            return response.token;
        });
    }
    IPToken = doSomething();
    console.log(IPToken);
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
       if (request.method == "getToken")
      sendResponse({token: localStorage["IPToken"]});// IPToken is just a string
  });
```

`IPToken` is always undefined. As I understand it, this is because the function won't wait for a response? If so, how can I make sure the response has returned before setting `IPToken = doSomething()` ?

**EDIT:** **I need the value of `response.token` further down in another function. This is why I'm trying to store the value in the var `IPToken`.**

UPDATE:

```
function onComplete(a){ // When the code completes, do this
    console.log(a);// this works, it returns the true result!!
    return a;
}

function getToken(whenDone){            
    setTimeout(function(){
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method: "getToken"}, function(response) {           
            whenDone(response.token);
        });
    },10);
}
var IPToken = getToken(onComplete);
console.log("Token is: "+IPToken);// undefined
```

Comment: You don't. You do something when the response is received.

Comment: @Barmar  You duplicate answer doesn't answer my question... All of that is related to Ajax, this has nothing to do with it. Never the less, I've tried something from that page but it's still undefined. See updated post...

Comment: There's nothing special about AJAX. You use the same techniques for all asynchronous actions.

Comment: I've added the code now. Well, if that's the case.. why am I still failing?

Comment: It makes no sense to use `return a` in an asynchronous callback function. Where do you think you're returning it to? The callback function is called asynchronously, when the response comes.

Comment: Put `IPToken = response.token;` in the callback function.

Comment: I don't understand, I'm just trying to store the response.token  globally

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91681/discussion-between-ashley-brown-and-barmar).

Comment: You can store it globally. But you can't access it immediately. Javascript is single-threaded, so the async function won't execute until you return to the main event loop. You can access the token later, once the async call has finished, for instance in another event handler.